# Conditions (allegedly..) sufficient on a nonabelian finite group -- involving the number of conjugacy classes -- for the centre to be nontrivial

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

I recently encountered a -- may I say -- ''cute'' looking problem in a textbook on group theory. In my own notations, here is the hypothesis. For arbitrary group $F$ the (cardinal) number of conjugacy classes of $F$ is denoted by $\mathrm{c}(F)$ and for arbitrary subset $X \subseteq F$ the centraliser of $X$ in $F$ is written as $\mathrm{C}_{F}(X)$. For arbitrary set $M$ the full symmetric group on $M$ shall be denoted by $\Sigma(M)$. $\mathbf{Gr}$ refers to the category of groups.

> Let $G$  be a *finite nonabelian* group and let us denote the largest prime divisor of the order $|G|$ by $p$. Given the relation $\mathrm{c}(G)>\frac{|G|}{p}$, prove that $\mathrm{Z}(G)$ is not trivial.

The problem follows the chapter which introduces group actions, representations by permutations, elementary properties of conjugation etc, so it should not require tools too sophisticated to solve (such as character theory).

My thoughts are to attempt *Reductio ad absurdum* by assuming the centre were trivial, to the effect that the number $\mathrm{c}(G)-1$ of *nontrivial* conjugacy classes is at least equal to $\frac{|G|}{p}$. This further means that at least one of these nontrivial classes -- say $C$ -- has cardinality strictly less than $p$, otherwise the union over all these classes -- expressible as $G \setminus \mathrm{Z}(G)=G \setminus \{1_G\}$ by virtue of our assumption and hence of cardinality $|G|-1$  -- has at the same time cardinality $\geqslant |G|$, which is absurd. Let us write $m=|C|$.

Thus, $G$ acts transitively (by conjugation) on $C$, action which induces a permutation representation $\rho \in \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{Gr}}(G, \Sigma(C))$. The kernel of this representation is clearly given by $\mathrm{Ker} \rho=\mathrm{C}_G(C)$, so it follows that $(G:\mathrm{C}_G(C))|\ m!$. If it were the case that $p$ divides this index we would derive $p|m!$, which is equivalent to $p \leqslant m$ and contradicts one of the previous conclusions. Hence we gather that $p|\ |\mathrm{C}_G(C)|$.....and what of it?!

The reasoning above doesn't take into account the special property that $p$ has (of being the maximum among the set of prime divisors of $|G|$), which is indication that it is perhaps not the way to go searching for a proof...

Attempting to reason by contradiction by means of assuming the existence of a minimal (in the sense of order) counterexample also doesn't seem too promising, since the behaviour of either centres or conjugacy classes is rather hard to control when passing on to subgroups, in general.

All in all the problem doesn't seem to conceal anything too profound, but alas I see myself lacking in ideas to approach it. Any word of advice shall be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which textbook are you referring to?

Comment: @Shaun one that is written in my mother tongue and therefore not necessarily among the most well-known or highly circulated textbooks. Worse still, the book gives no reference for the exercises presented (which I dare assume did not originate with the authors, but were taken from previous sources). In a direct translation, the title of the book is ''Elements of the theory of finite groups''.

Comment: What are the contents of the chapter it makes an appearance in? That might be a clue. (Although maybe you already incorporated that into your reasoning so far.)

Comment: @runway44 Let me go through them in order: 1) Actions and representations by permutations (generalities); 2) Transitive actions; 3) The orbits of an action; 4) Cycles and transpositions (application of 3) to finite degree permutations); 5) Actions by conjugation; 6) The multiplication of conjugacy classes (section which sets up the multiplication table of the centre of the group algebra over commutative rings, essentially); 7) Conjugacy classes of symmetric groups; 8) Conjugacy classes of alternatig groups. Simple groups (section which proves the simplicity of the alternating groups).

Comment: I'm sure I've seen this before, and forgotten how the proof goes. How I would start is to note as in the OP that there must be a conjugacy class with fewer than $p$ elements in it, say $x^G$ for some $x\in G$. Then the map $G\to \mathrm{Sym}(x^G)$ must have a kernel: this is because $p\nmid |\mathrm{Sym}(x^G)|$. Thus we have a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$, containing a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$, and contained in $C_G(x)$.

Comment: @David A. Craven Thank you for the suggestion. May a man dare ask where you remember having seen the problem before? (if you do remember, that is :)

Comment: No, I have no idea. It just sounds familiar.

Comment: So now I know I should be checking examples, the dihedral groups $D_{2p}$ satisfy $k(G)=(p+3)/2$ and $|G|=2p$, so $|G|/k(G)\to 4$ as $p\to\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statement is *not* true: take $G=S_3$, then the largest prime divisor of $|G|$ is $3$, and $c(S_3)=3 \gt \frac{6}{3}=2$, still $Z(S_3)=1$.

If $p$ is chosen to be the *smallest* prime, then it is true: assume that $Z(G)=1$, then note that for each $g \neq 1$, $\#Cl_G(g)=|G:C_G(g)| \geq p$. So the class formula gives us
$$|G| \geq 1 +p(c(G)-1)$$ and solving this for $c(G)$ we obtain $(1)$
$$c(G) \leq \frac{|G|+p-1}{p}.$$
But it is given that $$c(G) \gt \frac{|G|}{p}$$ whence $(2)$ $$ c(G) \geq \frac{|G|+p}{p}.$$
Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ now leads to $p \leq p-1$ a contradiction.

Comment: This is true, and I should have checked an example before thinking about it. What's the betting that it should be the *smallest* prime, not he largest?

Comment: Yes, then it is true, I will add the proof.

Comment: @Nicky Hekster Thank you for clarifying the situation. I should do a *mea culpa* in the following main regards: 1) I should have actually tried to apply the statement to easy cases to see if it holds; 2) I wanted to say in the original posting that the likelihood is not negligible for there to be typographic errors. The case so being I should have explored this hypothesis in which ''maximum'' is replaced with ''minimum''. All in all, good to have it settled.

Comment: @Nicky Hekster one more remark - made on an accordingly gesting tone - I fully disavow the problem as initially (and wrongly) stated, refusing to recognise any ownership of it :) It belongs not to me, but to that textbook where I found it.

Comment: @ΑΘΩ Are you actually 100% sure you transcribed/translated it correctly from the book? That's where a major source of such errors on MSE come from.

Comment: @ΑΘΩ Hey no big deal! Indeed it is a good practice to test small cases against a certain statement. And textbooks CAN be wrong. I have a slew of examples at hand, some even from very respected authors.

Comment: @David A. Craven 1000% sure about that.

Comment: @ΑΘΩ Then I recommend using a different textbook.